# SSIS error : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnections

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017, sql-server-2016, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2012

I am stuck with a SSIS error and have tried many things but still can't get this resolved. I would appreciate any help.

So give a background:

I have a class library ( many projects)  that is actually a pipeline components used by SSIS. Now  when I build these libraries ; I have a post  build event that copies the dll to 130 and 110 folder

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" -u $(TargetName)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" -i $(TargetFileName)
copy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents"
copy "$(TargetPath)" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\PipelineComponents"

and then register the dlls to GAC which I can verify here:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL

so far this is good. Then I use these as components in my SSIS project. And as per my understanding SSIS looks for the components in GAC. Now , I converted the SSIS to target sql -> 2016. Build performance is just horrible and it will take forever to build this.After I biuld the SSIS, i see on of the component with error:

@page { margin: 0.79in } p { margin-bottom: 0.1in; line-height: 115% }

[Read  File [2002]] Error: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'.

at BloombergCorporateActionsReader.CorporateActionsReader.AcquireConnections(Object transaction)

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostAcquireConnections(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper, Object transaction)

I tried googling this error but nothing of any help.

I am suing visual studio 2017 (SSDT) and sql server 2016.

I hope I was able to explain it clearly.

Thanks,

Rohit